# Validando dois campos de data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso verificar se o usuário informou a data em dois campos de data.

```
<input type="text" name="data1"/>
<input type="text" name="data2"/>
```

Como resolver isso?
Se eu colocar required no campo, só funciona no chrome. Mas e pro Firefox e Safari?

Veja @Renaro Santos

```
<script> 
function validar(){ 
var data1= document.getElementById("dataInicio").value; 
var data2= document.getElementById("dataFim").value; 
if(data1 == "" || data2=""){ 
alert('Uma das datas esta vazia'); 
return false; 
} 
} 
</script>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="validar()"> 
Data inicial<input type="text" id="dataInicio" name="dataInicio" required> 
Data Final<input type="text" id="dataFim" name="dataFim" required>
<input type="submit" name="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

Comment: o *input* do tipo *date* ainda não foi implementado em todos os navegadores então seu uso não é recomendado, 
dê uma olhada nesse plugin jQuery para validação: http://formvalidator.net/

Comment: Desculpe, na verdade estou usando type="text" e não date.

Answer (score 1):

Verificar se os campos estão vazios, voce pode fazer isto utilizando **Javascript** e **PHP**.

Coloque ID's  nos elementos:

```
<script>
    function validar(){
    var data1= document.getElementById("data1").value;
    var data2= document.getElementById("data1").value;

    if(data1 == "" || data2=""){
       alert('Uma das datas esta vazia');
       return false;
       }
    return true;

    }
</script>

 <form method="POST" action="action.php" onsubmit="validar()">
      <input type="text" name="data1" id="data1"/>
      <input type="text" name="data2" id="data2"/>
    </form>
```

***PHP*** (action.php)

```
<?php

$data1=$_POST['data1'];
$data2=$_POST['data2'];

if($data1 =="" || $data2 ==""){
  echo 'Uma das datas esta vazia';
  return;
  }

?>
```

Comment: Entendi @Renaro Santos, vou tentar.

Comment: não funcionou!
Como posso colocar meu código aqui para ele sair formatado?

Comment: Tente agora @GustavoSevero, se não funcionar, poste seu código e de mais detalhes...

Comment: Veja @Renaro Santos
{
<script>
function validar(){
 var data1= document.getElementById("dataInicio").value;
 var data2= document.getElementById("dataFim").value;

 if(data1 == "" || data2=""){
 alert('Uma das datas esta vazia');
 return false;
 }
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="validar()">
Data inicial<input type="text" id="dataInicio" name="dataInicio" required>
Data Final<input type="text" id="dataFim" name="dataFim" required><input type="submit" name="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
}

Comment: @GustavoSevero, coloque este código na pergunta para ficar mais fácil para ver...

Answer (score 1):

O erro tanto na pergunta do autor quanto na resposta do Renaro  Santos (`em javascript`) está nessa linha

`if(data1 == "" || data2=""){`

exatamente em `data2=""`

O correto é `data2 ==`

`if(data1 == "" || data2 == ""){`

```js
function validar(){ 
var data1= document.getElementById("dataInicio").value; 
var data2= document.getElementById("dataFim").value; 
if(data1 == "" || data2 == ""){ 
   alert('Uma das datas esta vazia'); 
   return false; 
} 
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="validar()"> 
Data inicial<input type="text" id="dataInicio" name="dataInicio" required> 
Data Final<input type="text" id="dataFim" name="dataFim" required>
<input type="submit" name="pesquisar" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```